# sign message with account imported from private key

Tags: solidity, web3js, accounts, signature

I try so sign my message but i have this error:

```
Error: Provided address [object Object] is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted.
```

```js
const web3 = new Web3(RPC_URL);
let accountSecretSigner = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x' + PRIVATE_KEY);
...
...
...
const signature = await web3.eth.sign(hash, accountSecretSigner);
```

I check my account and have address correct, so what's the problem?